# Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, gif

I am using android studio and added `compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.2'` in dependencies , it works well for Kitkat+ versions but after adding this in gradle i have inflating error for only kitkat version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.6.1'
```

then downloaded the source code of library and edited minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion , gradle version and CompileVersion to be the same as my project because it was higher and i still have the same exception

***this is my stackTrace:***

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
 at com.example.mmido.asfarandroid.AsfarApp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.moreholydays.asfartours-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.moreholydays.asfartours-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at com.example.mmido.asfarandroid.AsfarApp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you are using old/newest version of some library there is bugs, try on some versions, try to use + in the end of the library:
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
then press <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>, it will replace your version to the newest version, otherwise you can try to use older version, working for me many times.

Comment: Are you using multidex?